# Rails: Param is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to pass some params from a form to a view but all I get is `param is missing or the value is empty: quotes`. I've checked the database and the input is saved there but for some reason the data becomes `nil` somewhere along the way to the view.

I'm passing along the `:quotes` parameter from the view to the controller, and that should be it, shouldn't it?

**quotes_controller.rb**

```
class QuotesController < ApplicationController
def new
end

def create
  @quote = Quote.new(quote_params)

  @quote.save
  redirect_to @quote
end

def show
  @quote = Quote.find(quote_params[:id])
end

private
  def quote_params
    params.require(:quotes).permit(:title, :text)
  end
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<h2>Add Quote</h2>

<%= form_for :quotes, url: quotes_path do |f| %>
<p>
<%= f.label :title %><br>
<%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>

<p>
<%= f.label :text %><br>
<%= f.text_area :text %>
</p>

<p>
<%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<h2>Saved Quotes</h2>
<p>
<strong>Title:</strong>
<%= @quote.title %>
</p>

<p>
<strong>Text:</strong>
<%= @quote.text %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

I'm using the Rails Dev Box if that makes any difference.

Comment: I not very common to permit the `id`. But if you like to do so then `.permit` `id` as well.

Comment: Why would I want to do that? I'm only using the id to display the quote that was submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned the records are indeed getting saved to the database, new and create actions should not be a problem. However, when you do `redirect_to @quote` the id of @quote is available as params[:id] in show. So I think, modifying the show action in controller as below should work.

```
def show
  @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
end
```

On another note, you should consider modifying your create action to account for submissions for new quotes that don't pass the validations or don't get saved to the database.

```
def create
  @quote = Quote.new(quote_params)

  if @quote.save
    flash[:success] = "Successfully created the new quote..."
    redirect_to @quote
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

This would result in a friendly flash message to the user on the redirected page if the quote gets created. If not, it renders quotes#new to try another submission.

Comment: Your answer didn't fixed the problem, but it helped me to troubleshoot further. I have an <% end %> tag at the end of my show.html.erb which is what's causing the problem.

Comment: You can delete this `<% end %>` in show view and same story in new view.

Comment: @bork Glad I could help. Did you finally get everything right & running? @ PatNowak I don't think `<% end %>` in new.html.erb  is a problem. It's needed to close the `form_for` block.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is the view for `new` action. You don't have anywhere `quotes` instance variables set. Actually there should be `quote` there, but there is not.
Add in `new`:

```
 @quote = Quote.new
```

then use:

```
form_for(@quote)
```

in your new view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, after updating my code to your suggestion I'm still getting the same error.